# Invariance of a set of vectors under a matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If for some set of vectors $V$ and matrices $M$, $N$, $P$ and $Q$  of suitable size we have

$$(M+NP)V\subset V\hspace{2mm}\text{and}\hspace{2mm}(M+QR)V\subset V$$ do we necessarily have that $$(M+NKR)V\subset V$$ for some matrix $K$ of suitable size?

So far I've attempted some matrix manipulation along the lines of $(M+NP)(M+QR)V\subset V$ and $(2M+NP+QR)V\subset V$ but this seems to lead nowhere, as far as I can tell, and so I assume there's some trick that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the zero matrix, $N,P,Q$ and $R$ be the identity matrix, suppose $V$ is a one dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ $(n>1)$, if $K|_V\subset V^\perp$ (and $K|_V\neq \{ 0\}$) the relation clearly does not hold.

Comment: You should rewrite the question to include all the constraints on the matrices, maybe for certain constraints the equation holds. It still seems like there should be a counterexample that would be fairly easy to find if the only constraint is that each matrix is nonzero.